# RegExp: Look up non-formatted phone number with formatted number

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have an [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) formatted phone number and I want to look up any users with that phone number, though their number may not be formatted, what would that regex look like?

Example:

Given:

> +1234567891

Regex should match any of:

> (123) 456 7891
>
> 123-456-7891
>
> +1234567891
>
> 123.456.7891
>
> 1234567891

Any of the above with trailing or leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/\s*(\+)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})([ -.]|)\d{3}(\3)\d{4}\s*/
```

[See the regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/dI3sQ0/4)

---

## How it works

- `\s*` matches any preceding white space
- `(\+)?` optionally matches `+`
- `(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})` matches `(123)` or just `123`
- `([ -.]|)` matches  , `-`, `.` or nothing
- `\d{3}` matches `123`
- `(\3)` whatever was matches by `( |-|.|)`
- `\d{4}` match `1234`
- `\s*` matches any following white space

Comment: You don't need to use pipes when you have one char. you can change `( |-|.|)` to `[-. ]`

Comment: @DiogoDoreto +1 for the tip but a small issue, this won't match nothing. Needless I have updated my answer with your tip.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '+1234567891',
    parts = str.match(/\+((\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}))/).slice(1),
    num = parts.shift(),
    rg = new RegExp(
      '\\s*(?:\\+?' + [
        num,
        parts.join('.'),
        parts.join('-'),
        '\\(' + parts[0] + '\\) ' + parts.slice(1).join(' ')
      ].join('|') + ')\\s*');
```

In this case, it will produce

```js
/\s*(?:\+?1234567891|123.456.7891|123-456-7891|\(123\) 456 7891)\s*/
```

Comment: A completely fair interpretation of OPs question and an inspired piece of code. Could prove useful for a number of applications! +1

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is normalize both numbers and compare the result. You can, for example, remove everything that is not a number (`[^0-9]`) and compare only the digits left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
^\s?(\(\d{3}\)|\+?\d{3})([\s-.])?\d{3}\2\d{4}\s?$
```

Demo :https://www.regex101.com/r/jM2fF4/6

[image]